# Windows 7 won't boot and beeps on POST

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

I have a problem with my machine running Windows 7. The machine fails to boot but upon each failure, the behavior is erratic. Sometimes when I turn on the machine, nothing is shown on the monitor. At other times, the machine would boot but would freeze at the the window splash screen with the logo. During this time, the fan is runs very loudly. Finally, the most troublesome sign is a series of loud beeps on POST in the following pattern: short-short-long and this pattern repeats in groups of 3.

Some of the steps I have followed:

```
1). Scan for malware (Microsoft Security Essentials) with latest definitions. Results were clean.

2). Check for file system corruption: Chkdsk with automatically 
    fix system errors option selected. Log appeared normal

3). Check for corruption of basic Windows files through 
    Windows Resource Protection. No corruption was found. 

4). Use device manager to check status of all resource drivers.
    No yellow exclamations marks were seen.

5). Checked for memory problems using Windows memory diagnostic feature.

6). Clean boot by using the msConfig (system Configuration) utility 
    to clean boot the system, disabling all third party services.

7). Updated all device drivers from manufacturer updates.

8.) Did a clean reinstall from recovery medium. Worked for about several 
    months, but then the old problem came back. :(
```

I am running a a 64 version of Windows 7 Home Premium with SP 1 installed. My machine is a Omni 200 from HP. My BIOS manufacturer is American MegaTrends (AMI). At this point, I suspect a hardware issue (device driver) is at fault, given the POST beep.

Given the above, what else can I do to troubleshoot this problem. Are there any other diagnostics helpful for me to run?

Comment: If you're getting POST error codes, this is almost definitely a hardware issue. Look up the error code in your computer/motherboard's manual. First thing I'd suspect would be the RAM - you could try reseating them or running Memtest86+. Check the POST codes first, though.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for confirming my suspicion. I am suspecting the video / graphics card as been defective. Nothing appears on the monitor which would seem to back this up. Does this seem likely? MemTest86 was clear.

Comment: Yes, the video card is another common one. Do you have a discrete card? If so, try pulling it and using the onboard graphics. (Note: a proper memtest must be run for an extended period of time, often overnight, and should make 5+ passes. The more passes the better. Some transient errors can take a while to find.)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you get a POST code, follow it.  The Short-Short-Long in a repeating loop on a Intel G45S Express Chipset will probably match across boards.  [This Link](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/435598/Hp-Pro-3010-Microtower-Pc.html?page=3#manual) for the same chipset by same computer manufacturer shows that code as being a graphics card problem.  Along with the other things you have mentioned, reseat and mess with the graphics card.  If this does nothing, then replace or switch with known good card.  If the video is integrated, you would need a new motherboard.

This is not to say there is not another possible problem. But post codes do not happen randomly, especially when you are having "other" issues at the same time.